# JQuery not returning value? or the method is invalid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing my website right now, the website will have an API made with Javascript and jQuery. In a game named ROBLOX I'm trying to get the player's username just via his ID. The only problem is that the username label has no ID, so I get the username label via the class.

However when I call `innerHTML`, `innerText` or call the `.text()` method, it doesn't return me anything, however there IS text in there. Is there another way to get the text inside the object? It's basically The `class > h1 > text`. I'm not sure if I'm using the wrong methods. Could someone help?

```
function My(){
    var user_id = 97423773
    var lawl = ""
    $.get("roblox.com/users/" + user_id + "/profile", function(data, success) {
        lawl = $(".profile-about-content-text", data).text()
        alert(lawl)
    });
    return lawl
}
My()
```

Comment: Any error msg in your console?

Comment: I hope you have used semicolons in your actual code!

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Wouldn't the username be a part of the profile you're querying and contained in the `data` object returned by `$.get()`?

Comment: @MichaelL. Yes but it's HTML sir, i wanna get the text from the data itself but it somehow isn't giving me the text

Comment: Also, for getting the class selector to work with a provided context, the node with the specified class must be a _child_ node in the returned document fragment, not the root node.  Something like `<div><div class='foo'>username</div</div>` vs. '<div class='foo'>username</div>`.  This is because the selector will look _inside_ the root node, not at it.

Answer (score 0):

this is just working fine for me with semicolons added to the end of each line!
your URL is a bit peculiar as well not ending with / or file extention

```
"roblox.com/users/"+user_id+"/profile/"
"roblox.com/users/"+user_id+"/profile.php"
"http://www.roblox.com/users/"+user_id+"/profile/index.php"
```

Comment: Given that `$.get` is asynchronous, I'm interested in how you've tested it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've actually added a settimeout 4 seconds, it still isn't working

Comment: I'm not sure how `setTimeout` relates to this? If you refer to the question I marked as a duplicate you need to execute all logic dependant on the result of the `$.get` call in the callback handler.

Comment: I've used it because some people from the other replica of this thread have told me it's due to it being asynchronous, which means the program keeps on going even with the request still outbound

Comment: Rory is correct.  The logic to handle the results need to be in the callback handler.  Also, setTimeout does not 'pause'.  It is also an asynchronous function.  It continues normal code execution and then, after the specified delay, the function/code in the setTimeout is added to the event loop to be executed.

Comment: @MichaelL. Could you please link me to a good thread/question explaining that?!

Comment: function My(){
 var user_id = 97423773
 var lawl = ""
$.get("roblox.com/users/"+user_id+"/profile", function(data,success){
lawl = $(".profile-about-content-text", data).text(function(){
   return lawl
});
}
My() would this work?

Comment: This blog post by John Resig (who created jQuery) is a primer on how setTimeout works: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: @RbxDealsOwner You don't want to pass a function into `.text()`.  The 'callback' is the function passed as the second parameter to `$.get`.  Everything you want to do with `data` needs to be handled within that function.  Also, because it is asynchronous, you can't 'return' a value from that function to the 'calling code'.  So instead of trying to return the value, you would want to grab it from the data and then immediately do something with it or pass it to another function.

Comment: @RbxDealsOwner Also, take a look at this tutorial explaining asynchronous code in JS: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/event-based-programming-what-async-has-over-sync--net-30027

Comment: Hi All I have put alerts and return a dummy test and the code works fine buy putting semicolons. not if the get doesnot return anything that is either URL or something relating to the server that we do not have the access to the code.

Comment: @MichaelL. I've taken your advice highly into appreiciation, and tried working something out, however it stills alerts with emptiness function Alert(Arg){
 alert(Arg)
};

function My(){
alert("ok");
var user_id = 97423773;
var lawl = "";
$.get("roblox.com/users/"+user_id+"/profile", function(data,success){
lawl = $(".profile-about-content-text", data).text();
Alert(lawl);
})
}

Comment: @RbxDealsOwner If this is the actual code then I will update my answer. let me know please.

Comment: @DanielPurPur Yessir.

Comment: By the way guys, when i tested this in an extension or console, it worked, it just wouldn't work on my website

Comment: that is why I am saying it is a url or server matter. your code looks fine to me.. obviously with semicolons! included

Comment: Also see my updated answer regarding the URL please.

Comment: @RbxDealsOwner Did you see my last comment on the original post, noting that the node with the class must be a _child_ of the root and _not_ the root itself, for the `$('.class-name', context).text()` jQuery syntax to work?  Also, don't create your own `Alert` function, just use the standard `alert` function.

Comment: Also, @DanielPurPur, to Rory's point, could you post a link to an example of it 'working with semicolons'?  You _might_ have gotten the alert to work, but I don't see how the `return lawl` statement could work, given that `$.get()` is asynchronous.

Comment: I have used a different url (my own) but the same structure, hence saying this could well be a problem on the server side code. One thing I would like to know is ... Do you see any errors in syntax apart from the ones I mentioned?